# how to convert unordered list( UL, LI) to continuous string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert following html code into continuous string using jquery/javascript.

```
<ul> 
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

This is the html placed inside the textarea(with id "description") when I read these contains using  `$('#description').text()`, I get this description as

```
one 
two 
three
```

instead I would like to get it as "one two three" i.e. continuous, any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove line breaks.

```
someText = $('#description').text();
someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

Or replace them with spaces:

```
someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
```

--
http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/javascript-line-breaks.php

Comment: #1 seems to work for me..I had tried it with ("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'')..I guess my regex was incorrect....can you pleae explain what's the purpose of "gm" in regex

Comment: thanks.... got it....The "gm" at the end of the regex statement signifies that the replacement should take place over many lines (m) and that it should happen more than once (g).

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression and remove line breaks and white space

```
var final = $('#description').text().replace(/[\n ]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

give the same name attribute for all li's. like

```
<ul> 
    <li name="common">one</li>
    <li name="common">two</li>
    <li name="common">three</li>
</ul>
```

Now you can get all by `var text=document.getElementsByName('common');` Append `text[i].value` upto `text.length`